# VBA SQL Right Join - Syntax Error in Join Operation

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm trying to Right Join a sub query in Excel VBA but I keep getting a syntax error. Can anyone spot it?

```
SELECT c.Category
FROM [Catalogue Info] as c

RIGHT JOIN (
SELECT [Product Code]
FROM Orders
WHERE JSID = 10503001
AND [Delivery Date] >= 04/12/2017
GROUP BY [Product Code]
) AS o ON c.code = o.[Product Code]

WHERE c.Brand='Brand'
AND c.Category<>''
GROUP BY c.Category
ORDER BY Avg(c.Page) Asc;
```

Excel 2016
Windows 10

---EDIT---

This is the actual code in VBA that produces the above query

```
sqlProdList = " RIGHT JOIN" _
    & " (SELECT [Product Code]" _
    & " FROM Orders" _
    & " WHERE JSID = " & customerRef _
    & " AND [Delivery Date] >= " & Date - 365 _
    & " GROUP BY [Product Code]) as o on c.code = o.[Product Code]"

sqlCategory = "SELECT c.Category" _
    & " FROM [Catalogue Info] as c" _
    & sqlProdList _
    & " WHERE c.Brand='Brand'" _
    & " AND c.Category<>''" _
    & " GROUP BY c.Category" _
    & " ORDER BY Avg(c.Page) Asc;"
```

This is what the tables look like:

[image: Catalogue Info Table Details]

[image: Order Table Details]

Comment: A syntax error is quite subtle - could it be this line?
```AND [Delivery Date] >= 04/12/2017```

Comment: I have tried the code with & without this line and I am still given the same error. I have also tried this line of code with other queries and works fine.

Comment: If it's the ODBC driver coughing up the error (and not VBA itself) then I suspect it's your date literal which should be ANSI format `YYYY-MM-DD` and surrounded by single quotes (RDBMS dependent though). Try instead `" AND [Delivery Date] >= '" & FORMAT(Date - 365, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "',"  _`

Comment: If it's VBA itself throwing this error (not the RDBMS or ODBC driver) then you'll have to share more code, as the code you have shared is 100% fine.

Comment: @JNevill MS-Access is the RDBMS so I would expect it to use the same date format as Excel. Formatting `YYYY-MM-DD` I'm afraid makes no difference.

Comment: Also this `JSID` bit. If that is a non-numeric field that will also have to gain string encapsulation like `WHERE JSID = '" & customerRef & "'" _` although, not knowing your data, that is hard to say. Please share the schema of the tables involved here as it may help.

Comment: If it's MS Access, then quote that date with #

Comment: Since this access, instead of trying to do the date math in excel and hoping you are sending the correct date literal to Access (currently you are not) instead do the date math in access `" AND [Delivery Date] >= DateAdd("d", -365, Date())" _`  This is all easily checkable though by printing out the results of `sqlCategory` and applying it directly in your database. Get it written correctly there where it's much easier to debug, then shoehorn it back into excel.

Comment: @JNevill My gut is telling me that this is not a problem with the date format. I have used the above code in other queries and faced no problems. Even when removing the line entirely I am still given a syntax error.

Comment: @dorn I disagree, but this is SUPER easy to test. Run your code, but output the SQL in that variable to somewhere where you can copy/paste it. Paste it into access (a new Query, using the SQL view) and run it. Does it run? If so, then you are fine and this is probably a VBA error, not a database error. Does it not run, throwing a syntax error, then... troubleshoot your sql before heading back to VBA. The way you have it written now is that Access is going to interpret that as math. and 4 divided by 12 divided by 2017 is probably not what you want.

Comment: @JNevill As you thought, running the same query in Access SQL Query builder returned incorrect results. Adjusting the date parameter to `Format(Date() - 365, "YYYY/MM/DD")` worked correctly, so did `DateAdd("d", -365, Date())`, but I'm afraid neither of these work when moved back in to VBA.

Comment: I would use the `DateAdd()` version, just make sure it's inside your double quotes when setting your sql string variable. You want to send that formula to Access for it to evaluate. If it's outside quotes and concatenated then VBA will evaluate, which is not what you want.

Comment: @JNevill Now we're making progress... this seems to be working. I have errors further along in the code that I will correct & then I'll post the correct answer when I'm happy all is working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Read comments on OP for debugging help.

Issue was with the date formatting. The problem query passed from Excel VBA to Access was `AND [Delivery Date] >= 04/12/2017`

Access was interpreting the date as maths, and therefore evaluating 4/12/2017 rather than treating as a date field.

Passing `DateAdd("d", -365, Date())` in to the query as a string was allowing Access to evaluate it's own date parameter.

### Final working code

SQL

```
SELECT c.Category
FROM [Catalogue Info] as c

RIGHT JOIN (
SELECT [Product Code]
FROM Orders
WHERE JSID = 10503001
AND [Delivery Date] >= DateAdd("d", -365, Date())
GROUP BY [Product Code]
) AS o ON c.code = o.[Product Code]

WHERE c.Brand='Brand'
AND c.Category<>''
GROUP BY c.Category
ORDER BY Avg(c.Page) Asc;
```

VBA

```
sqlProdList = " RIGHT JOIN" _
        & " (SELECT [Product Code]" _
        & " FROM Orders" _
        & " WHERE JSID = " & customerRef _
        & " AND [Delivery Date] >= DateAdd('d', -365, Date())" _
        & " GROUP BY [Product Code]) AS o ON (c.code = o.[Product Code])"

sqlCategory = "SELECT c.Category" _
        & " FROM [Catalogue Info] as c" _
        & sqlProdList _
        & " WHERE c.Brand='Brand'" _
        & " AND c.Category<>''" _
        & " GROUP BY c.Category" _
        & " ORDER BY Avg(c.Page) Asc;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the query you want is more like this:

```
SELECT c.Category
FROM [Catalogue Info] as c LEFT JOIN 
     [Product Code]
     o.Orders o
     ON c.code = o.[Product Code] AND
        o.JSID = 10503001 AND
        [Delivery Date] >= '2017-04-12'
WHERE c.Brand = 'Brand' AND c.Category <> ''
GROUP BY c.Category
ORDER BY Avg(c.Page) Asc;
```

Note:

- This uses `LEFT JOIN`.
- It fixes the date format.
- It removes the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

The date value must be preceded and followed by a # sign.

```
qlProdList = " RIGHT JOIN" _
    & " (SELECT [Product Code]" _
    & " FROM Orders" _
    & " WHERE JSID = " & customerRef _
    & " AND [Delivery Date] >=#" & Date - 365 _
    & "# GROUP BY [Product Code]) as o on c.code = o.[Product Code]"

sqlCategory = "SELECT c.Category" _
    & " FROM [Catalogue Info] as c " _
    & sqlProdList _
    & " WHERE c.Brand='Brand'" _
    & " AND c.Category<>''" _
    & " GROUP BY c.Category" _
    & " ORDER BY Avg(c.Page) Asc;"
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe "SELECT c.Category
FROM [Catalog Info] as c "into the c.code field.

Comment: I have tried this code already if that's what you mean: `SELECT c.code, c.Category FROM [Catalogue Info] as c` it gives the same syntax error.

Comment: Date information must also be in quotation marks. for example [Delivery Date]> = '04/12/2017'